# Retrieve data from mongodb with binary type

Tags: mongodb

I have a site that I created using mongodb but now I want to create a new site with MySQL. I want to retrieve data from my old site (the one using mongodb). I use RoboMongo software to connect to mongodb server but I don't see my old data (*.pdf, *.doc). I think that the data is in binary, isn't it? [image: This is my mongodb]

How can I retrieve this data?

Comment: I assume you used GridFS to store the files?

Comment: i'm not sure. I hire a guy to code this site. Which code you need to help me Markus W Mahlberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary data you've highlighted is stored using a convention called [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/). Robomongo 0.8.x doesn't support decoding GridFS binary data (see: [issue #255](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/255)).

In order to extract the files you'll either need to:

- use the command line [`mongofiles` utility](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/) included with MongoDB. For example:

  - `mongofiles list` to see files stored
  - `mongofiles get` *filename* to get a specific file
- use a different program or driver that supports GridFS

Comment: thanks for your answer.... can you give me code in linux to decoding GridFS binary data?

Comment: @PhamVanSon You should be able to use the [`mongofiles` utility](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/) to extract the files. It's included as part of the full MongoDB install, or in a separate package that just should be called `mongodb-org-tools` for recent versions of MongoDB.